# Entity Framework does not load child table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

There is a EF project that is used by an ASP.NET MVC app. The EF project was built on a legacy database (using a database-first approach).

When I try to load child records for a `Machine` the collection `Maschinentagessaetze` stays empty, even though there are records in the database with the correct foreign key.

Is there any way to debug this? I have no idea what the problem could be? From what I found on the internet, this should work.

```
// Controller
Machine = db09.Maschinen
              .Include(x => x.Maschinentagessaetze)
              .FirstOrDefault(x => x.DMasId == id);

// after this line, Machine.Maschinentagessaetze is empty

var MachineTagessaetzeList = db09.Maschinentagessaetze.Where(x=> x.OMaschineFk == id).ToList();
//after this line, MachineTagessaetzeList is filled with Machine also beeing loaded
//when this line is active, Machine.Maschinentagessaetze is filled
//whitout this line, it stays empty 


// Models
[Table("t_Maschinen")]
public partial class TMaschinen
{
        public TMaschinen()
        {            
            Maschinentagessaetze = new HashSet<TMaschinentagessaetze>();            
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("d_MAS_ID")]
        public int DMasId { get; set; }

        [Column("o_Bezeichnung")]
        public string OBezeichnung { get; set; } = null!;
       
        public virtual ICollection<TMaschinentagessaetze> Maschinentagessaetze { get; set; }
}

[Table("t_Maschinentagessaetze")]
public partial class TMaschinentagessaetze
{
    [Key]
    [Column("d_MTA_ID")]
    public int DMtaId { get; set; }

    [Column("o_Maschinentagessatz")]
    public decimal OMaschinentagessatz { get; set; }

    [Column("o_Maschine_FK")]
    public int OMaschineFk { get; set; }

    // with [ForeignKey("OMaschineFk")] the problem remains
    public TMaschinen TMaschinen { get; set; }
}

// DbContext
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public virtual DbSet<TMaschinen> Maschinen { get; set; } = null!;
public virtual DbSet<TMaschinentagessaetze> Maschinentagessaetze { get; set; } = null!;

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TMaschinen>()
            .HasMany(m => m.Maschinentagessaetze)
            .WithOne(t => t.TMaschinen)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.OMaschineFk);
}

// In the database, there is a foreign key constraint on the child table:
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[t_Maschinentagessaetze] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_t_Maschinentagessaetze_t_Maschinen] 
        FOREIGN KEY([o_Maschine_FK]) REFERENCES [dbo].[t_Maschinen] ([d_MAS_ID])
            ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: What happens if you load a single `Maschinentagessaetze` and include the parent `Maschinen`? Does it find the correct `Maschinen`, or is it null? 
Also, are you using Entity Framework, or Entity Framework Core?

Comment: See updated code, if I load a list of 'Maschinentagessaetze', the machine property is filled,. I use 'EntityFrameworkCore'

Answer (score 0):

I consider you should refact OnModelCreating method:

Parent Entity

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TMaschinen>()
         builder.ToTable("TMaschines");
        builder.HasKey(i => i.Id);
        builder.Property(i => i.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();//you decide how to generate id
        builder.Property(i => i.OBezeichnung )
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .IsRequired();
```

Child Entity (Add propertites that are missing)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TMaschinentagessaetze>()
        builder.ToTable("TMaschinentagessaetzes");
        builder.HasKey(i => i.Id);
        builder.Property(i => i.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); //you decide how to generate id
        .HasOne(m => m.TMaschinen )
        .WithMany(t => t.Maschinentagessaetze )
        .HasForeignKey(m => m.OMaschineFk);
```